# Draw initial point and initial value for legend

Tags: dygraphs

I have disabled the display of both axis to draw something similar to a sparkline, I also enabled the permanent legend, but the initial value is empty.

Is it possible to set an initial location for point when the graph is first drawn? f.e. this can be the last point drawn, and then the legend would show current/latest value, similar to how sparklines are generally drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should rtfm better, it is easy enough http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#setSelection.

```
graph.setSelection(data.length - 1)
```

The above is enough to make it display the last point in the data, assuming `data` holds native format values.